# crontab -e with jump to line option?

Tags: cron, vim

My $EDITOR is `vim` and when launching vim the direct way, you can jump directly to what you are interested with the `+/` option. For example:

```
vi /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root +/rsync
```

But using the actual recommended command `crontab -e` I don't see an obvious way to do that. Does anything exist?

Comment: You could do `EDITOR="$EDITOR +/rsync" crontab -e` I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what distribution you are using, but in Debian at least the source code just gets [VISUAL or EDITOR](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/blob/master/crontab.c#L379), [appends the filename](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/blob/master/crontab.c#L412) and forks.

So in that case no, you cannot pass additional parameters from the command line to your editor when using `crontab -e`.

You could rebuild the VISUAL or EDITOR variables each time though, as another answer suggests.

Comment: Looking at the source you referenced and applying [steeldriver's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594465/crontab-e-with-jump-to-line-option/594473#comment1109233_594465), it seems that you CAN pass additional parameters when using `crontab -e`

Comment: That's why I specified that 'crontab -e' would not cut it, on its own. Of course, because the command line is built each time, you can rebuild your `VISUAL` (or `EDITOR`) variable as you wish and it will work. A `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi +3` will open with the cursor on the third line.  I'll make it clear in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar to this function, which allows me to edit the `crontab` file in the way that you want, committing changes only once I've written out the file

```
vicrontab() {
    local cf="$HOME/.crontab" md5
    crontab -l >"$cf"
    md5=$(md5sum "$cf")
    "${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}" "$@" "$cf"
    [[ "$(md5sum "$cf")" != "$md5" ]] && crontab "$cf"
}
```

Although I would tend to use it simply as `vicrontab` there's no reason why it couldn't be invoked as `vicrontab +/rsync`